# Problem marking Gnosis Safe as a Proxy to interact with it in Etherscan

Tags: gnosis-safe

I made a safe a long time ago and eventually updated it to 1.3.0 when that came out. But now I have made a second safe just today. When I compare the Contract Source Codes on Etherscan, they have different licenses (MIT vs GNU LGPLv3) and for the old one I can mark it as a proxy, but the new one will not let me do so. It gives an error of basically not being able to find an implementation contract. The safes are both on 1.3.0, but I guess changes were made to the licensing and maybe the way the smart contract is built? Is there a way to fix it? Is it better to use a really old safe that has been updated or a brand new one?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.